# How do I properly build a volume group and logical volume for 500GB in AIX?

Tags: storage, aix

I've been fiddling around with AIX 5.3.7 for hours today, and I was able to build a VG and LV, but I'm having difficulty using all the space in the LUN I carved out (500GB).  I'm not sure if i'm running the right commands.

I have the LUN mapped from the SAN to the AIX box as **hdisk16**

I have the PV activated:

```
chdev -l hdisk16 -a pv=yes
```

I have the VG created:

```
mkvg -y logBUVG01 -s64 hdisk16
```

I have an LV created:

```
mklv -c1 -t jfs2 -y fslv01 logBUVG01 1
```

I go to format it:

```
crfs -v jfs2 -A yes -g logBUVG01 -m /fslv01 -a size=500G
```

But it fails saying I don't have enough free partitions.  I don't understand how AIX determines space from the number of logical partitions or PP size, etc.  If someone could clear this up for me, it would be great.  How do I build my volume group/logical volume to utilize all the space I've carved out of my LUN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I couldn't use ``-a size=500G`.

Changing my command to use `-a size=500000M` worked:

```
crfs -v jfs2 -A yes -g logBUVG01 -m /fslv01 -a size=500000M
```